# MSSQL and MySQL as Linked Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, encoding

I have a MSSQL Server 2005 and MySQL Server as linked server.
I want to save particular data from MSSQL to MySQL.
And I have a huge problem related with encoding.

**MS SQL**

```
select SERVERPROPERTY ('collation')
Result: Cyrillic_General_CI_AS
```

**MySQL**

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';
+--------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name            | Value  |
+--------------------------+--------+
| character_set_client     | utf8   |
| character_set_connection | utf8   |
| character_set_database   | utf8   |
| character_set_filesystem | binary |
| character_set_results    | utf8   |
| character_set_server     | utf8   |
| character_set_system     | utf8   |
+--------------------------+--------+
```

When I'm trying to retrive data from MySQL or to insert ones to MySQL
I have a wrong character set in text field,
something like that "???????????????"

How can I convert text data to UTF-8 encoding before inserting the data to linked server?

Or should I change some settings?
I don't want to change encoding of MySQL server on CP-1251, it's not convenient for me.

Answer (score 0):

What is your [Collation Compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186839.aspx) property for linked server? [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/02/14/how-it-works-linked-servers-and-collation-compatibility.aspx) might help.
Have you tried [COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx)?